# On the History of Double Adjunts

Tags: logic, predicate-logic, first-order-logic, math-history, adjoint-functors

I have been reading some texts by Joaquim Lambek on formal languages, grammar and so on, and at some point he mentions that the kind of approach he advocates in the late 90s and 2000s has the advantage, as compared to some similar ones from the end 60s, that they allow for double adjoints, which, in turn, account for what other schools address with the use of traces.

Does that mean that double adjoints were ony developed in logic and mathematics in the 70s or later? Or how should I understand that claim?  I am assuming that the authors in the 60s were not simply oblivious

I would be very grateful if you could me illustrate me on the history of double adjoints, with references, milestones, etc...

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I know absolutely nothing about the topic, but I would think this kind of question - history - would be better addressed on the math overflow site, as that's where 'the elders' congregate.

Comment: I have just created a thread there, as suggested. Anyway, I would be very thankful for contributions and help here.....

Comment: For the convenience of the reader: your math overflow question is https://mathoverflow.net/questions/287408/on-the-history-of-double-adjunts